# Who gave the Cloak of Invisibility to Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, deathly-hallows, invisibility-cloak

On his first Christmas at Hogwarts, Harry received his invisibility cloak with a note which said:

> Your father left this in my possession before he died. It is time it was returned to you. Use it well.

But there is no name/initial at the end of this note, so who sent it to Harry?

Comment: Dumbledore gave it to him.

Comment: Could the down voters explain why this question was bad ?

Comment: Because we find out later on that Dumbledore gave Harry the cloak.